# correct definition of methods Laravel 4

Tags: function, laravel, controller

I have a question what would be the correct way to define methods within controllers.

I see many tutorials on using (index, show, create, store, edit, update, destroy) and in another use the following (getIndex, getShow, getCreate, postCreate, getEdit, postEdit).

the wake of this would like to know from the experts, which model to follow ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a Laravel problem and there is no "correct" way for a Laravel application, it's up to you, but there are some rules to follow in some cases.

#### Resourceful Controller Methods

The methods you listed are basically the Rails restfull ones:

```
index, show, create, store, edit, update, destroy
```

And they are automatically created by Artisan when you do:

```
php artisan controller:make ControllerName
```

Also a Laravel Restful route will expect them:

```
Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
```

#### RESTful Controllers

Here Laravel will try to automatically guess the kind of HTTP method your controller accepts and build all routes for you. So, if you have a route:

```
Route::controller('PostController');
```

And your PostController class having a method

```
public function getIndex()
{
    ...
}
```

You are telling Laravel to create a route GET to that method.

#### It's up to you

If you create all your routes manually, you could do:

```
Route::get('users', 'UsersController@usersIndex');
```

Pointing to

```
public function usersIndex()
{
    ...
}
```

And Laravel will not force you do any of those others ways.

#### Docs

Take a look at the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Here's some documentation about this in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html